# With Travis-CI, how do I test chrome packaged apps?

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, google-chrome-app, karma-runner

I am writing a chrome packaged app, using angular JS.

My setup uses grunt/karma/jasmine for building/unit testing, and everything was fine until I started using the chrome.* API. This of course was an issue as I had Travis-CI set up to use PhantomJS, but Phantom doesn't know about the `chrome` global var.

1. Is there a way to run unit tests with karma that will not throw `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: chrome` for testing packaged apps, and so pass Travis-CI testing
2. Is there a way to suppress the errors that PhantomJS is throwing (this sounds bad already)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few thoughts:

1. You could polyfill/stub the chrome.* apis before running your tests, to simulate the chrome app environment.  Not sure if anyone has already done this already (i.e. here is one quick [example for node-webkit](https://github.com/jamesmortensen/node-webkit-chrome-api-stubs/blob/master/chrome-api-stubs.js) I found).  It sounds like a useful library someone should write ;)
2. Just skip those tests that you know will always fail on PhantomJS, by wrapping jasmine test definitions with a guard like `if (!is_chrome_app) return;`.  One clean way to do this in jasmine is to create a `defineChromeAppOnly` helper that skips the define call if its not a chome app.
3. You probably want an alternative system for actually running tests inside a real chrome app.  I've always just built my own crude CI for this (or done it manually), but since this would be cool to make easier for CI, I've filed a [request with Travis CI Team to support Chrome Packaged Apps](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2213).  Star that issue if you are interested in what they reply.